# How do i fetch data from RTDB while ensuring the data i fetch are not duplicates of the ones i already have?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I have a list a students in Firebase RTDB, and I want to rank them based on their test scores. Here's what the data looks like in JSON.

```
{
  "students": {
    "student_id_1": {
      "name": "alpha",
      "score": 100
    },
    "student_id_2": {
      "name": "beta",
      "score": 70
    },
    "student_id_3": {
      "name": "gamma",
      "score": 100
    },
    "student_id_4": {
      "name": "delta",
      "score": 60
    },
    "student_id_5": {
      "name": "epsilon",
      "score": 90
    },
    "student_id_6": {
      "name": "zeta",
      "score": 75
    },
    "student_id_7": {
      "name": "eta",
      "score": 100
    },
    "student_id_8": {
      "name": "theta",
      "score": 90
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see from the data, there are multiple students with perfect scores. In the case of fetching, say 8 students at the time, when there are more than 8 students with perfect scores, how do I prevent the RTDB Query from fetching the same data it has fetched before?

This is the query I currently have, and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
refAudit.orderByChild('score').endBefore(lastItem).limitToLast(itemCountPerPage)
```

I'm doing all of this in Flutter, hence the code. I might have confused what the variable `lastItem` should contain. As of right now, I'm just following what I've read and assigned `lastItem` with a List containing the key of the data and the score since that's the parameter for the order of the Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to see if we work with hard-coded values for a bit.

Let's say that you want to get the last/top 3 scores, you can do that with:

```
refAudit.orderByChild('score').limitToLast(3)
```

From a quick check that should give you the 3 players who have scored `100`, nodes `student_id_1`, `student_id_3` and `student_id_7`.

---

Now say you want to show the next 3 top players with a score lower than that, which you can do with:

```
refAudit.orderByChild('score').endBefore(100).limitToLast(3)
```

This gives you the players with a score lower than 100, `student_id_5`, `student_id_8`, and `student_id_6`.

Continuing this, you can paginate backwards through all players.

---

There's a potential problem with the above in the case that multiple players have the same score and it doesn't align on a page size.

Say that we want to read 2 players at a time, so we get the two top scores with:

```
refAudit.orderByChild('score').limitToLast(2)
```

And that gives us nodes: `student_id_3` and `student_id_7`.

Now we want to read the next top scores, one of which still scored `100`. If we do the query we used above, we would not get that final `100` scorer.

What we need to do extra here is pass in the key of the last/first node we retrieved:

```
refAudit.orderByChild('score').endBefore(100, 'student_id_3').limitToLast(3)
```

Now the database has enough information to know that it needs to still return  `student_id_1` and it'll return nodes: `student_id_1` and `student_id_8`

Comment: Thank you for answering.

So from my case, I need to change what I passed in the value `lastItem` to match the previous query.

However, I'm slightly confused as to why the first query return `student_id_3` and `student_id_7` and not `student_id_1`. Is it caused by the limitToLast() method?